# interpreting RMSE when variables are transformed and compare it with no-transformed variables model

Tags: r, regression, interpretation

I want to compare different models for biomass estimation using different dasometric variables of trees. To achieve this I am using three models with the original variables and three models using transformed variables (transformation applying logarithms to the dependent and independent variables). To know which models are best, those which present original variables or transformed, I get different goodness-of-fit data  (R2, R2 revised and RMSE.) My question is: can the RMSE of both models be compared without applying any transformation to the models with transformed variables? I get RMSE values of 8-24 for the original variables and 0.6-0.8 for the transformed variables.
For the statistic calculations, I am using R software

Edited: I have to use inverse log transformation to get RMSE in the same scale. ¿How can i do it?

Comment: This is really a question for Stack Exchange rather than Stack Overflow, but I'd say no, your instinct is correct; to compare RMSE across those models, you'd need to get the values back on the same scale one way or the other.

Comment: RMSE is calculated based on how much your predicted values deviate from observed. Models with transformed dependent variables will have different scales of RMSE compared to those not transformed..

Comment: If you want to see how good your models are, one alternative is to use something like correlation coefficient.

Comment: @StupidWolf Same issue there. Possibly they could use R^2 of back-transformed prediction vs observed values.